# Нужно ли второе С?

Tags: стилистика

Как лучше сказать: "Он был с хвостом и с крыльями" или "он был с хвостом и крыльями"?

Comment: Можно сказать и так, и так, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Контекст бы...

Вообще-то есть (неимперативная) рекомендация предлоги по возможности не отбрасывать.
Но в нашем случае вступает в действие элементаное соображение. Если "хвост и крылья" по мысли автора воспринимается как нечто единое (ну, скажем, детали самолета), то смысла во втором предлоге нет.
Но ежели это что-то совершенно не связанное, даже противопоставляемое, как, например, намек на то, что в персонаже было что-то и от ангела, и от черта, то второй предлог напрашивается сам собой.